# Where does Cabal install a package globally on a Mac?

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

In macOS, if I execute

```
cabal install foo --global
```

where does `cabal` install the *foo* package?

Comment: I suspect this information might be in `.cabal/config`, but I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: You can ask with `ghc-pkg list --global` to get the location of the package list and `ghc-pkg describe --global <package-name>` to get further details on the files created for that package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one place GHC stores global data—it depends on the configuration and that will vary by where you got [GHC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasgow_Haskell_Compiler) from (nixpkgs, [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) (`brew`), [MacPorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts), raw from GHCHQ, etc.).  For your particular case, you can get information as described [by DanielWagner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50801998/where-does-cabal-install-a-package-globally-on-a-mac/74121592#comment88611981_50801998):

```
ghc-pkg describe unix --global
```

And some simple shell scripting can extract the specific information you desire:

```
ghc-pkg describe unix --global | egrep '^pkgroot' | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Output:

```
"/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/8.4.1/lib/ghc-8.4.1"
```

Or:

```
% nix-shell -p ghc
ghc-pkg describe unix --global | egrep '^pkgroot' | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Output:

```
"/nix/store/z0ypzmbhn6m0l2adzm8szcd72z7kwy04-ghc-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

The setting for your user is in `~/.cabal/config`, in the `install-dirs global` section, under `prefix:`. (E.g. on Linux, it is pre-set to `/usr/local`.)

Although in my cabal, for some reason `--global` does the same thing as `--user`, according to the `man` page.

I would avoid using it.